# How do you make leg pole and target bones for a model?

Tags: animation, rigging

I've been working on a tutorial from Imphenzia to model a low-poly Mandalorian, but I'm having difficulty in making leg poles because the video is going too fast for me to catch up to. How do I make efficient leg poles and target bones for a character model in Blender?
https://youtu.be/szIvkd1NBz4?t=876

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The knee needs to be bent a bit forward in *Edit* mode, which is already the case. Create the pole target bone (pt) and the controller (ctrl), parent them to the root bone (parent the bottom spine to the root as well), parent the foot to ctrl (maybe also try to parent pt to ctrl), give the IK constraint to the shin, set the constraint correctly: ctrl is the *Target* bone, pt is the *Pole Target*, you'll probably need to set the *Pole Angle* value, set the *Chain Length* to 2:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131084/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-how-do-you-make-leg-pole-and-target-bones-for).